# Capture canvas screen as video using Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, video-capture, screen-capture

I have Silverlight application which have Bing Maps Silverlight control for map visualization. User can fly from location to location on map, add pins and every other map related stuff. My question is is it possible to capture video of canvas in my silverlight app where map is? So that user can specify draw me a route from A to B, and then my SL app will programmatically capture map screen and produce it like a video.

I was able to do that with WPF and Expression encoder SDK, but I'm afraid that this is not possible with SL (expression encoder + SL). Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could capture the users actions (they clicked X and Y elements and typed Z into the textbox), then you could use those same actions to generate a video on the server.

A lame basic way to accomplish this is to open the site in a browser on the server, use video capture software to capture the browser window, and then inject the users actions programmatically. Of course this would be a terribly heavy application, but it's all I could come up with. Perhaps it'll spark a better idea.

As a side note, I highly doubt Silverlight can capture the browsers screen as this would be a major security flaw. Imagine hidden Silverlight controls capturing a user's actions without their knowledge.